# How to capture frame from playing video without OpenCV method

Tags: python-2.7

I want to capture the frame from playing video without using OpenCV method.
I need to capture 25frame per second for 25FPS playing video 
How to do this with python

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4
```

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Alternatively, you could try using pyscreenshot and setting a timer to have it capture every 1/25th of a second.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

#grab partial screen
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 125, 375, 550))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2

# save image file
im.save(filepath)
```

Comment: I Tried the below code, but it captures 40 frames only for 30 Second videos.

import os
import pyautogui
import time
import threading

t_end = time.time() + 60 * 1

def play_video():
    print "Inside thread"
    os.system("vlc.exe --no-qt-privacy-ask --fullscreen --play-and-exit textinmotion.mp4")

time.sleep(5)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=play_video, args=[])
t1.start()
print "Before 4 loop"

for i in range(200):
    print "Inside 4 loop"
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    pic.save("images/"+str(i)+'_Screenshot.png')